# How to get http response in php ratchet

Tags: php, http, websocket, ratchet

I am going to build a system which will receive a streaming raw data form browser. Data will use websocket to transmit and receive, then system will keep going to send chunk data to HTTP server. Flowchart show below:
[image]

First, I separate websocket server and HTTP client into 2 program, both can work. websocket server use `ratchet`, HTTP client use `stream_socket_client` and `stream_select`.

Then, I try to combine websocket server and HTTP client together, I can receive data from browser but I cannot get any response from HTTP server. How can I get HTTP response in Ratchet? Many Thanks.

The following is my php code:

**Chat.php**

```
<?php
namespace MyApp;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

function read_response_code($response){
    foreach (explode("\n", $response) as $a) {
        if (strpos($a, 'HTTP/1.1') !== false) {
            $arr = explode(" ", $a);
            if ($arr[1] != "100")
            {
                return 0;
            }

            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
class Socket implements MessageComponentInterface {

    protected $clients;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
        $this->SERVER = "tcp://192.168.0.1:80";
        $this->socket = [];
        $this->clients->connect = 0;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // Store the new connection to send messages to later
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
        
        echo "Try to  connect http server...\n";
       
        $this->socket = stream_socket_client($this->SERVER, $errno, $errstr, 30);

        if (!$this->socket){
            //disconnect websocket
            $conn->close();
        }
        else{
            $header = "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                    . "Host: 192.168.0.1\r\n"
                    . "Accept: */*\r\n"
                    . "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n"
                    . "Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n"
                    . "Expect: 100-continue\r\n\r\n";

            $written = fwrite($this->socket, $header);

            $response = fread($this->socket, 100);

            $ret = read_response_code($response);
            if ($ret == 0)
            {
                echo "Connect HTTP server fail.\n";
                $conn->close();
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Connect success!!!!\n";
                $this->clients->connect = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        //combine http client
        if ($this->clients->connect == 1)
        {
            $read   = array($this->socket);
            $write  = NULL;
            $except = NULL;

            $num = stream_select($read, $write, $except, 0, 400000);
            if ($num === false) {
                /* Error handling */
            }
            elseif ($num > 0) {
                // cannot read any response
                echo "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            }
            else {
                // send data to HTTP server
                $size = strlen($msg);
                $hex = dechex($size);

                fwrite($this->socket, "$hex\r\n");
                $written = fwrite($this->socket, $msg);
                fwrite($this->socket, "\r\n");
            }

        }
       
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // The connection is closed, remove from connection list
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

**Chat-server.php**

```
<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Chat;


require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$loop = \React\EventLoop\Factory::create();

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new Socket()
        )
    ),
    8080
);

$server->run();
```

**HTTP_client.php**

```
<?php

$SERVER = "tcp://192.168.0.1:80";
$SEND_STATUS = 0;

$file = fopen("test.raw", "rb");
$socket = stream_socket_client($SERVER, $errno, $errstr, 30);

$header = "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
        . "Host: 192.168.0.1\r\n"
        . "Accept: */*\r\n"
        . "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n"
        . "Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n"
        . "Expect: 100-continue\r\n\r\n";
$written = fwrite($socket, $header);

$response = fread($socket, 100);

function send_data($file, $socket, $bytes) {
    global $SEND_STATUS;

    if ( feof($file) ) {
        $SEND_STATUS = 1;
        fwrite($socket, "0\r\n\r\n");
        fclose($file);
        return(false);
    }
    $buffer = fread($file, $bytes);
    $size = strlen($buffer);
    $hex = dechex($size);
    fwrite($socket, "$hex\r\n");
    $written = fwrite($socket, $buffer);
    fwrite($socket, "\r\n");
}

while (true) {
    $read   = array($socket);
    $write  = NULL;
    $except = NULL;

    $num = stream_select($read, $write, $except, 0, 400000);
    if ($num === false) {
        /* Error handling */
    }
    elseif ($num > 0) {
        foreach ($read as $r) {
            echo "xxxxxxxxx";
        }
    }
    else {
        if ( $SEND_STATUS === 0 ) {
            send_data($file, $socket, 16000);
        }
    }
}

?>
```